# In Swift, how do you find UILayoutGuide objects in a view controller?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm creating a sudoku style swift app using 81 buttons (organized in stack views).
 I'm referencing the buttons using their tag value 0 to 80 which aligns with the arrays I'm using to store the values.
 But, the first button is causing problems, I think because there are UILayoutGuide objects that also have tag 0.

This solution was working but I've just upgraded to Xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a) and converted to swift 3.

I added the following code to the viewDidLoad function of the view controller:

```
// Get the subviews of the view
var subviews = view.subviews

// Return if there are no subviews
if subviews.count == 0 {
    return
}

for subview : AnyObject in subviews{

    // Do what you want to do with the subview
    print("\(subview.tag) - \(subview)")

}
```

This produces the following log:

> Optional(200) - UIImageView: 0x7ff3e240f3b0; frame = (-4 0; 383 667); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 200; layer =
>
> Optional(200) - UIStackView: 0x7ff3e240f590; frame = (7 103; 360 360); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 200; layer = CATransformLayer: 0x6100002316a0
>
> Optional(200) - UIImageView: 0x7ff3e24111b0; frame = (0 47; 375 436); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 200; layer = CALayer: 0x6100002344e0
>
> Optional(200) - UIToolbar: 0x7ff3e2637ff0; frame = (0 623; 375 44); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 200; layer = CALayer: 0x6000000343e0
>
> Optional(200) - UIImageView: 0x7ff3e26015f0; frame = (63 228; 248 211); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 200; layer = CALayer: 0x600000034ea0
>
> Optional(200) - UILabel: 0x7ff3e263e2e0; frame = (117 313; 141 41); text = 'Nice Work'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 200; layer = _UILabelLayer: 0x600000093060
>
> Optional(200) - UIStackView: 0x7ff3e263e750; frame = (127 491; 120 120); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 200; layer = CATransformLayer: 0x600000035520
>
> Optional(0) - _UILayoutGuide: 0x7ff3e263ee80; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = CALayer: 0x600000035bc0
>
> Optional(0) - _UILayoutGuide: 0x7ff3e263f030; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = CALayer: 0x600000035c60

So the last 2 output lines are my suspected UILayoutGuide objects. I didn't code them and they are not objects in the hierarchy. How do I see them/get rid of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer is that the UILayoutGuides don't have tags. When you print the subview.tag its showing tag = 0 when there is no tag. So the issue with button 0 is not related to the UILayoutGuide.

I didn't figure out what the issue was with the tag 0 button but recoded to avoid using tag 0. Not exactly fixed but the solution works.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to prevent the loop from adding the _UILayoutGuide (which is of class UILayoutSupport), do this:

```
// Get the subviews of the view
var subviews = view.subviews

// Return if there are no subviews
if subviews.count == 0 {
    return
}

for subview : AnyObject in subviews{

    // Do what you want to do with the subview
    print("\(subview.tag) - \(subview)")

    // Check for whether is it a UILayout class or not
      if(subview is UILayoutSupport){
            //This section is executed when UILayoutGuide will come into play
            print("Don't add it to the stack")
       }else{ 
            // Write your code in this section
       }

}
```

you can also print your stack, check for UILayoutGuide in it and remove it.

Comment: I was just using the loop to show that the UILayoutGuide objects exist within the ViewController. I didn't create them intentionally and I don't see where they are within the model. My code references tag id 0 which I want set for 1 button (within the stack) but because of these layout guides there are 3 objects with tag id 0 which causes a crash when referencing the button by tag id. So I want to delete the UILayoutGuide objects or change their tags but I don't know how to find them.

Comment: @StruanK :- Bydefault each element has a tag 0, so you can't use it directly. What u can do is at the time you are giving tag, use (0 + Some Int value). And at the time you are using that element subtract that Int Value.